# Split text into differents processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to divide a string between the different processes, each process will take a part of the string and apply the split () function, what happens is that I don't know how to make each process take a part of the string without cutting the word, for instance:

```
0 received:  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's sta
1 received:  ndard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a typ
2 received:  e specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
3 received:   essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
4 received:  passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```

I want the process 0 take "standard" instead of "sta".
How I can get this?

```
import concurrent.futures


def split_text(text, process_id):
    print(process_id, "received: ", text)
    return text.split()


def main():
    text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and " \
           "typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's " \
           "standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown " \
           "printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type " \
           "specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also " \
           "the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. " \
           "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets " \
           "containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing " \
           "software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"

    n_processes = 5
    results = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for process_id in range(n_processes):
            results.append(executor.submit(split_text, text[int((process_id / n_processes) * len(text)):
                                                            int(((process_id + 1) / n_processes) * len(text))],
                                           process_id))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use `split` to divide the paragraph into words, and then dole out a number of words to each process, instead of a number of letters.

Comment: @TimRoberts  I know, but I want to send the text to the processes without performing the split operation, since I want each process to do it separately

Comment: The only other way is to simulate the split.  Start at the spot you WOULD have chosen, then back up until you find a space and break there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
import concurrent.futures

def split_text(text, process_id):
    print(process_id, "received: ", text)
    return text.split()

def dole( body, chunk ):
    start = 0
    while 1:
        i = chunk
        if start+i >= len(body):
            return body[start:]
        while body[start+i] != ' ':
            i -= 1
        yield body[start:start+i]
        start += i + 1

def main():
    text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and " \
           "typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's " \
           "standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown " \
           "printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type " \
           "specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also " \
           "the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. " \
           "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets " \
           "containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing " \
           "software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"

    n_processes = 5
    results = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for process_id, chunk in enumerate(dole(text, len(text)//n_processes)):
            results.append(executor.submit(
                split_text, 
                chunk,
                process_id))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```